# Как запустить свою функцию до смены ориентации приложения на экране

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Есть проблема с функциональностью. Она решилась тем, что я получаю у приложения все изменения положения получая сообщения по `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`.

Но мне нужно для чистоты решения вызывать мою функцию только при смене положения из портретного в ландшафтное и наоборот. А точнее перед тем, как приложение поменяет ориентацию. Но я не нашел решения как это сделать.

Еще раз суть вопроса. Нужно понять как отловить момент перед тем, как приложение изменит ориентацию.

Пока мысль остановилась на поисках того, как через `NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver` выловить текущий угол наклона или что-то подобное.

Буду очень рад любой помощи. Уже перепробовал много вариантов решения окольными путями, но толку не дало.

Comment: Это поможет? "method is invoked when rotation takes place." https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/UIKit.UIViewController.ViewWillTransitionToSize/

Comment: Посмотрите тут: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577000/608343

Comment: Всем спасибо за идеи. В итоге создал renderer страницы нужной и переопределил метод public override void WillRotate (UIKit.UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation, double duration)

Answer (score 1):

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class SomePageView : ContentPage
{
    SomePageView()
    {
        this.SizeChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```